# Swap left and right cameras in multiview vision

Tags: opencv, 3d, camera-calibration, multiview

I have two cameras (left and right) and I use multiview geometry to find out depth of some point (by using triangulation). If I swap the images (due to other reasons), do I need to flip point coordinates as well, i.e.

```
x = width - x
```

My guess is yes, but I'd love to hear some good reasoning behind this. Thank you.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear? Can you support it with some illustration ?

Comment: If you swap the images, the perspective becomes incorrect and you will not be able to calculate the depth; you would have to *flip* the entire image horizontally